# Finding the average value of a function over an interval.

Tags: calculus

[image: Image attached]

I'm having trouble finding the areas between the intervals, mainly because I know that in order to use the mean value theorem for integrals, you (probably) need an equation for f(x). But since they are simply supplying the graph, I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Decompose the interval first and integrate for each sub-interval.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fact that the definite integral of a function is equivalent to the area under the curve.

If you aren't given an explicit formula for $f$, then look for shapes that you know area formulas for (from the gold ole' geometry days perhaps).

Comment: It is not generally equivalent. However, here, it is true.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  The non-zero part of the graph of $f$ is a triangle with base $1$ and altitude $1$, so its area is...?

Comment: I tried that, the answer would be .5 (correct) since it represents a triangle with base 1 and height 1, multiply that by 1/2 and you would get .5. The rest of the interval's area would be 0, so the answer should be .5?

Comment: That is the correct first step.  But check out what is meant by average value of a function, it's not just the area under the curve.

Comment: True, I used the formula for MVT for Integrals and I got the correct value for the area of f(x) [Answer is: (1/4)]. But for g(x), would it be the same process since its discontinuous?

Comment: Yes it would be the same process.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot the units of the graph were different. How would I go about completing the last step? I've read that the integral from a to b of f(t)g(t)dt would be equal to f(c) = the integral from a to b of g(t)dt. Is this simply implying that its the area of g(t)?

Comment: Work out what the graph of $f(t)g(t)$ looks like - it's very simple - and calculate the average value in the same way as above.  Don't try anything complicated ;-)